# Python error in a colon.. cant find an answer

Tags: python

As part of a piece of python work I have to ask for a first name and surname, then repeat it three times if it is correct. When I try it Python puts a syntax error on the colon. What do I need to do to correct it?

[Basically whats going on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCux7.png)
I've already tried removing the colon, bringing the if line down to one equals, and looking for bracket errors, but I cant find anything.

Comment: Please paste the code with your question.

Comment: You should learn about the `if` syntax first. Also, you should remember the importance of indentation in python

Comment: `if input==yes:` instead of `if: input==yes`

Comment: In addition to the above points, you need `firstname = input()` and the same for `surname`

Comment: I saw put a colon in the if command, guess I didn't look at placement properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The colon should be at the end,

```
if input == yes:
```

However I cannot see how this can work? Is that the full code? If so, what is the `yes` variable?

If it was intended to be a string, the line should be,

```
if input == "yes":
```

The `""` tells Python that it is a string (a word).

A link to Python syntax: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics

Comment: This is something I must have forgotten to do, As I remember being taught this.

Comment: Okay, don't worry, these things can slip when you're starting out ;)